# Multiple Select onChange create dynamic fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to accomplish when an option is selected/unselected on a multiple select the onChange event will call a function to add or remove the dynamic field that is selected/unselected.

I've been trying for a few hours to think of the best logical approach to get this to work.

```js
$('.multi-select').on('change', function() {
  $.each($(this).val(), function() {
   /* [ Some logic to check if a dynamic input should be removed or added. ]*/
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="multi-select" multiple>
  <option value="0" selected>Col 0</option>
  <option value="1">Col 2</option>
  <option value="2" selected>Col 2</option>
  ...
</select>

<div class="dynamic-fields">
  <input type="text" name="option[0]" value="asc">
  <input type="text" name="option[2]" value="desc">
</div>
```

I just need some guidance with the best approach that I should take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your question, every time the user select one or more elements from the selectbox a function must do:

1. if element is selected and already present in the div area: do nothing
2. if the element is  selected and not present in the div area: insert
3. if the element is not selected --> remove the element from the div area

The difficulty here is to select an element by name where the name attribute contains a square bracket.

```js
$(function () {
  $('.multi-select').on('change', function(e) {
    var cacheEle = $('.dynamic-fields');
    $(this).find('option').each(function(index, element) {
      if (element.selected) {
        if (cacheEle.find('input[name="option\\[' + element.value + '\\]"]').length == 0) {
          cacheEle.append('<input type="text" name="option[' + element.value + ']" value="' + element.text + '">')
        }
      }  else {
        cacheEle.find('input[name="option\\[' + element.value + '\\]"]').remove();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="multi-select" multiple>
    <option value="0" selected>Col 0</option>
    <option value="1">Col 1</option>
    <option value="2" selected>Col 2</option>
</select>

<div class="dynamic-fields">
    <input type="text" name="option[0]" value="asc">
    <input type="text" name="option[2]" value="desc">
</div>
```

Comment: That's perfect. Looking at that now it all makes sense :) The way I was thinking was just over complicated!

Thank you.